# Why does the below code returns wrong answer?

Tags: java

Here I'm comparing **ArmstrongNo** & **out** were both have same values(**371**), but is printing the wrong statement.

```
public class ArmstrongNumber {

static int ArmstrongNo = 371;
static int sum = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArmstrongNumber am = new ArmstrongNumber();
    int out = am.Armstrong();
    System.out.println(out);
    if (ArmstrongNo == out)
        System.out.println("It is an Armstrong number");
    else
        System.out.println("Not an Armstrong number");

}

public int Armstrong() {

    int length = String.valueOf(ArmstrongNo).length();// To find the length of integer
    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        int i = ArmstrongNo % 10;
        int cube = i * i * i;
        sum += cube;

        ArmstrongNo = ArmstrongNo / 10;
    }
    return sum;
 }

}
```

OUTPUT:

371

Not an Armstrong number

Comment: Why are you comparing an object to an `int`?

Comment: @Jim How can I fix this code?

Comment: @JimGarrison The code isn't doing that (wouldn't compile). It's just weird variable names.

Comment: peaple answered it correct, but you can change ArmstrongNo to armstrongNo so no one think it is Object :))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 4):

you are overwriting your `ArmstrongNo` here `ArmstrongNo = ArmstrongNo / 10;`

sum is then 371 but ArmstrongNo is 0

**EDIT**

this fixes your code (at least functionally)

```
public int Armstrong() {
        int ArmstrongNoCopy = ArmstrongNo;
        int length = String.valueOf(ArmstrongNoCopy)
                .length();// To find the length of integer
        for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
            int i = ArmstrongNoCopy % 10;
            int cube = i * i * i;
            sum += cube;

            ArmstrongNoCopy = ArmstrongNoCopy / 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method `public int Armstrong()` modifies static variable `ArmstrongNo`. To avoid this, do declare this static variable as `final` and add local variable to the method `public int Armstrong()`:

```
final static int ArmstrongNo = 371;

public int Armstrong() {

    int ArmstrongNo = ArmstrongNumber.ArmstrongNo;
    //...
}
```